# What is the replacement for tools.nsc.io.File?

Tags: scala

In scala 2.3.0 the

```
   tools.nsc.io.File
```

class seems not to be publicly accessible (and obviously it's earlier incantation that was something like `compiler.nsc.io.File` is also not around anymore..) Is there a drop-in replacement available for it?

Comment: What on earth made you use such ancient version of Scala? The class itself is/was in the compiler package which I believe never was a public, maintained API.

Comment: umm no. the `compiler` version was old.  But  the `tools.nsc.io.File` is more recent - i'm actually unclear what is its status with scala 2.11: is it deprecated or not

Comment: You might be looking for `scala.reflect.io.File`

Comment: ah yea - that's right .  A workaround is to add the `scala-compiler` to the maven project. But the `scala.reflect.io.File` is the better choice. You can make that an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment of @ghik (feel free to create your own answer) we could use `scala.reflect.io.file`.

Comment: Why on earth are adding `scala-compiler` as a dependency to your project? Is your project somehow a component of the scala-compiler?